# Reading csv file in vba not moving to next record, rather next column

Tags: vba

Below is code from an Access application. What is taking place is a csv file is being read that contains records. If correct conditions are not met then the program needs to move on to the next record in the csv file and continue to process. However, when this happens at the line "GoTo NEXT_RECORD" It immediately jumps to "NEXT_RECORD: Wend" and starts the loop over again. However, instead of reading the next record it reads the next column. I need to know how to move the pointer to the next record and not the next column. Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Sub ReadCSV()

    Const FILE_NAME = "C:\files\test.csv"

    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim sX As String
    Dim sSSN As String
    Dim sName As String

    Open FILE_NAME For Input As #1

    'read to the end of the line to skip header row
    While sX <> Chr(13)
        sX = Input(1, #1)
    Wend
    sX = Input(1, #1)

    While Not EOF(1)

        Input #1, sSSN

        If Len(sSSN) <> 11 Then
            Debug.Print "bad SSN: " & sSSN
            GoTo NEXT_RECORD
        End If

        Input #1, sName
        Debug.Print sSSN & vbTab & sName

NEXT_RECORD:
    Wend

    GoTo FINISH
EH:
    With Err
        MsgBox .Number & vbCrLf & .Source & vbCrLf & .Description
        .Clear
    End With

FINISH:
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The CSV file has records like this:

```
SSN,Name
684-92-4567,Marshall Applewhite
55589,Shoko Ashara
874-96-5124,Jim Jones
```

Comment: This isn't all the code. For example, where is NRec defined? Please take this chunk of code and put it in a new file with Option Explicit and compile it. Then add anything that is missing. -- Or -- remove anything that won't compile and boil your problem down to something we can compile.

Comment: Don, my apologies. I thought I had enough code shown to help resolve the issue. I have now put all the code in above. I have also made the file Option Explicit and compiled it. Sure enough there are many variables that are not defined. I am new at vba and Access. So, this is helpful. What I really need to do at this point is just to get this working. Personally I want to do a rewrite. Much of this seems cryptic. With the entire code now listed above can you give me some more direction? Do you see anything that stands out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Read to the end of the line before resuming the loop. This will bypass the other fields. Here is some code doing just that using the Input Function to read one character at a time until it comes to a Carriage Return (character 13). It then reads one more character to bypass the Line Feed (character 10). Windows uses a combination of Chr(13) and Chr(10) for line endings.

Place the following lines right before the Goto, so they look like this:

```
'read to the end of the line
sX = ""
While sX <> Chr(13)
    sX = Input(1, #1)
Wend
sX = Input(1, #1)

'now safe to move to next record
GoTo NEXT_RECORD
```

This is a repeat of several lines of code toward the beginning of the routine which do the same thing in order to skip the header row of the CSV.

The Input # Statement is used to read one field at a time (it reads to the comma or end-of-line), so that's why you have skip to the end before resuming.

**References**

- [VBA Input Function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Input-Function-5a666c45-6048-405f-bdfe-c5209c45756d)
- [VBA Input # Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243386(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Don, this works and resolves the issue. You are welcome to edit my question and example. Thank you for the help. I have found several good resources (books) and will be do much reading. I will up your answer as soon as your edits are complete.

Comment: That original code is pretty cryptic. Work through it line by line and write comments as you figure out what each line does. Also, step through line by line using {F8} to see what is happening with a known csv file.

Comment: Got it. I started to going through it with option explicit on and it wouldn't compile. So after declaring my 8th or so variable I knew I needed to document and plan for a rewrite in the near future. Thanks again Don for all your input and help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you check this answer as the correct one it's worth another 15 rep to me.